# Make 8 images using each bit of each pixel of an image

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, matrix

so I have a 512x512 grayscale image and I want to use each bit of the pixels of the image to make 8 different black and white images, each one with the respective bits. To achieve this I'm using the opencv library.
The grayscale image `x_img_g` is represented by a matrix:

```
[[162 162 162 ... 170 155 128]
[162 162 162 ... 170 155 128]
[162 162 162 ... 170 155 128]
...
[ 43  43  50 ... 104 100  98]
[ 44  44  55 ... 104 105 108]
[ 44  44  55 ... 104 105 108]]
```

[You can see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Gjt.png)

I think I managed to make the image with the most significant bit which I made like this:

```
def makeImages():
    y = x_img_g>128
    cv2.imshow('BW',np.uint8(y*255))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Which makes this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vPFc.png)

But I'm having trouble making the other images so I would really aprecciate any help.

Oh and if anyone can explain this also, I would like aswell to make an image with only the 4 most significant bits of the `x_img_g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend to `3D` with a new axis at the end and use [`np.unpackbits`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html) along the same -

```
np.unpackbits(a[...,None], axis=-1) # a is input array
```

Sample run -

```
In [145]: np.random.seed(0)

In [146]: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(2,3),dtype=np.uint8)

In [147]: a
Out[147]: 
array([[172,  10, 127],
       [140,  47, 170]], dtype=uint8)

In [149]: out = np.unpackbits(a[...,None], axis=-1)

In [150]: out
Out[150]: 
array([[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Hence, `out[...,0]` would be the binary image with the least significant bit and so on until `out[...,7]` as the one with the most significant bit.

Alternatively, putting it in another way, we could extend with a new axis along the first axis -

```
out = np.unpackbits(a[None], axis=0)
```

Hence, `out[0]` would be the binary image with the least significant bit and so on until `out[7]` as the one with the most significant bit.

Comment: @youknowwho Accepting answers is better than thanks. Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Just did it, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow so I didn't know I could accept answers. I just didn't upvote beacuse I need 15 reputation.